# content query webpart, query filter on a hidden field?

Tags: content-query-web-part

i am using o365, and building a sharepoint 2013 Online website.

i have created a column in my contenttype. I set This column hidden.

i dont see This column when i try to add a query filter on my CQWP?

Answer (score 1):

i belive that the hidden attribute make it hidden to the UI (user interface) hence why you dont see it, I think you can only use the OM (Object model)

you could try adding this xsl to the cqwp to see if it would return all fields!

```
<xsl:template name="AllFields" match="Row[@Style='AllFields']" mode="itemstyle"> 
<xsl:param name="CurPos"/>  <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">  
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">  
<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>  
</xsl:call-template>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="SafeImageUrl">  
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">  
<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'ImageUrl'"/>  
</xsl:call-template>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">  
<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">  
<xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>  
<xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>  
</xsl:call-template>  
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="LinkTarget">  
<xsl:if test="@OpenInNewWindow = 'True'" >_blank</xsl:if>  
</xsl:variable>  
<div id="linkitem" class="item">  
<xsl:for-each select="@*">  
<span style ="font:bold">    
<xsl:value-of select="name()" /> 
</span>  : <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
<br/>  
</xsl:for-each>  
</div>  
</xsl:template>   
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

http://spyralout.com/2009/10/30/cqwp-content-query-web-part-display-all-fields-values/

if the above doesnt work than you could try this method that someone outlined:

witin the .webpart file you need to manually add the fields:

```
<property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string">ParentListName;ParentListUrl</property>
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">ParentListName, Text;ParentListUrl, Text</property>
<property name="GroupBy" type="string">ParentListName</property>
```

and then the xsl would look somthing like this:

```
    <xsl:template name="CustomLinkedHeader" match="*" mode="header">
     <div class="groupheader item medium">
       <a>
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:value-of select="@ParentListUrl"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetGroupName">
         <xsl:with-param name="GroupName" select="@*[name()=$Group]"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="GroupType" select="$GroupType"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
       </a>
     </div>
   </xsl:template>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx

http://www.fftf.org/news/Mar09feed/Content_Query_Web_Part_querying_by_content_type_grouping_results_by_the_parent_list.rss.html